# Struggling with Sum Macro

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a macro which takes an invoice I have copied into a worksheet, and copies the premium amount and pastes it onto the summary tab in the cell that corresponds with the same social security number on both sheets.  Here is the macro:

```
Sub Eyemed2()
Dim rw, LastRow, LastRRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, Found As Range, SheetEnd3 As Range
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Eyemed 2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Raw")
LastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Set rng = ws2.Range("A2:B" & LastRow)    
LastRRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
For rw = 14 To LastRRow     'Begin in row 14 of Eyemed 2
    If Not ws1.Range("R" & rw) Is Nothing Then    
is blank
        Set Found = rng.Find(What:=ws1.Range("A" & rw).Value, 
LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not Found Is Nothing Then
            ws2.Range("N" & Found.Row) = ws1.Cells(rw, "J").Value

        Else
            Set SheetEnd3 = rng.Find(What:=ws1.Range("A" & rw).Value, 
      LookIn:=xlValues)
            LastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            ws1.Range("A" & rw).Copy ws2.Range("B" & LastRow)
            ws2.Range("N" & SheetEnd3.Row) = ws1.Cells(rw, "J").Value

        End If
    End If
Next rw
End Sub
```

So it looks at column R in 'Eyemed 2' and if it isn't blank, then copy over the cell in column N into the summary tab, column J.  It finds the appropriate row to paste in the summary tab by searching for the social security number in column A of 'Eyemed 2' in column A:B in the summary tab.

My issue is that in 'Eyemed 2', some of the social security numbers are listed more than once with two different amounts.  So I need to edit the macro to sum all amounts with the same social security number and then search and paste into one entry in the summary tab as opposed to now where it just copies and pastes one amount.

Thank you very much

Comment: Use 'FindNext', if you are recording the macro it's one further step.

Comment: I suggest you post a screen shot of you data. It seems that the task is much easier with a `SUMIF` formula.

Comment: You have a few options you can use for this, and it depends on your comfort level with Excel and VBA. On the less advanced end, just use a PivotTable with SSN's as the Row, and the Totals as the value. You can then use a similar approach to what you have, and it will give you the accurate sums. On the other hand, a more advanced approach would be using the Scripting.Dictionary Object. Given your current code, I would strongly recommend the former approach. It will be easier on your for the short term.

Comment: `If Not ws1.Range("R" & rw) Is Nothing` here you're testing whether the range is an object - that will always be `True`.  Maybe you meant `If Len(ws1.Range("R" & rw).Value) > 0 Then`

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple matches then this just leaves you with the last value found:

```
ws2.Range("N" & Found.Row) = ws1.Cells(rw, "J").Value
```

...but this will add each value to any previous value

```
With ws2.Range("N" & Found.Row)
    .Value = .Value + ws1.Cells(rw, "J").Value
End with
```